# Deploying spring boot micro services with K8's in production

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, kubernetes, microservices

I'm new to k8's setup, I wanted to know what is the best way to deploy the services in production. Below are a few way's I could think of, can you guide me in the right direction.

```
1) Deploy each *.war file into a apache tomcat docker container, and using the service discovery mechanism of k8's.
2) Run each application normally using "java -jar *.war" into pods and expose their ports using port binding.
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest to use docker based approach. I never tried running app directly into pods.

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati i'm trying to do docker based approach, but i'm confused whether to deploy my services to a Apache tomcat docker container or run as normally as "java -jar *. war" in my docker containers directly and expose the ports in production ?

Answer (score 4):

The canonical way to deploy applications to Kubernetes is as follows:

1. Package each application component in a container image and upload it to a container registry (e.g. Docker Hub)
2. Create a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#deployment-v1-apps) resource for each container that runs the container as a Pod (or a set of replicas of Pods) in the cluster
3. Expose the Pod(s) in each Deployment with a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#service-v1-core) so that they can be accessed by other Pods or by the user

Comment: so i need not deploy to a apache tomcat docker container and then expose it, rather Expose the pods directly in production ?

Comment: First create containers, then deploy the containers to the cluster as Pods with a Deployment, then expose the Pods with a Service.

Comment: currently, we have created services and deployments files and running the same and it works fine, my question is in the production environment do we follow the same approach or should we introduce a standalone tomcat server for each service and deploy the apps in them, this is where i'm confused ?

Comment: That's a question of how you want to design your containerised application, i.e. what to put in a container: multiple services in the same container or each service in a separate container? That's a question you have to decide independently of Kubernetes, and once your containerised app is working (e.g. locally with Docker), you can deploy it to Kubernetes.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use embedded Tomcat server in Springboot .jar file to deploy your microservices. Below the answer of @weibeld that I also use to deploy my springboot apps.

1. > Package each application component in a container image and upload it
   >   to a container registry (e.g. Docker Hub)

You can use [Jib](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib) to easily build distroless image. The container image can be built using [maven plugin](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#quickstart).

```
mvn compile jib:build -Djib.to.image=MY_REGISRY_IMAGE:MY_TAG -Djib.to.auth.username=USER -Djib.to.auth.password=PASSWORD
```

2. > Create a Deployment resource for each container that runs the container as a Pod (or a set of replicas of Pods) in the cluster

Create your deployment .yml file structure and adjust the deployment parameters as you need in the file.

```
kubectl create deployment my-springboot-app --image MY_REGISRY_IMAGE:MY_TAG --dry-run -o yaml > my-springboot-app-deployment.yml
```

Create the deployment:

```
kubectl apply -f my-springboot-app-deployment.yml
```

3. > Expose the Pod(s) in each Deployment with a Service so that they can be accessed by other Pods or by the user

   kubectl expose deployment my-springboot-app --port=8080 --target-port=8080 --dry-run -o yaml > my-springboot-app-service.yml

   kubectl apply -f my-springboot-app-service.yml